# Stuck on media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm stuck trying to extend a couple of media queries.

I've got one max-width based query and one min-width based one that looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/* styling goes here */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* styling goes here */
}
```

I would like to extend the first query to also make it enabled on any device that recognizes itself as being in portrait orientation and likewise extend the second query to trigger when having a device that is not in portrait mode.

The second media query (the min-width based) should never apply while in portrait mode, regardless of the device width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not looking for the `AND` operator, but the `OR` one, which in the CSS world is just a comma. Hence you can do things like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px),
screen and (orientation:portrait) {
     /* styling goes here */
}
```

However, in order to achieve the result you wish you would have to invert the order of your queries so that they can **cascade correctly**. This is because, for example, in the iPad, even in *portrait* orientation you are going to have a `min-width: 600px`, evaluating one of the two statements to true and hence triggering the media query.

By putting the `portrait` media query below the `landscape` one, you will actually make sure that when the `orientation` query evaluates to `TRUE` you will be overriding the previous styling.

You can see a modified working version of your JSBin here:

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/ikovud/3)</kbd>

Try this with the iPad. Though being larger than 600px in portrait mode, it will still display: *small-screen*.

Comment: I think this is basically what I was looking for. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `and (orientation:portrait)` or `and (orientation:landscape)` to your media queries.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (orientation:portrait) {
   /* styling goes here */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (orientation:landscape) {
   /* styling goes here */
}
```

***EDITED***
Based on your JS Bin example, although I'm still not 100% sure what your issue is, you can remove the "white gap" you get by removing the (orientation: landscape) from the second query.
I suspect the first one isn't triggering in your ipad as the max-width is wrong, I believe it should be 768px for an ipad (see [The Responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com/) for a guide).

Comment: Yes, but at the same time I want devices that don't get the orientation query to have the styles of the query apply. Would that be possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "devices that don't get the orientation query"?

Comment: I put together a demo to make this easier to grasp: http://jsbin.com/ikovud/1/

The first query should always trigger in portrait mode on any device that is capable of that, and it should also work at a max-width of 600px. The second should always trigger in landscape mode or at min-widths of 600px. Try it out on a high res iPad for example, and I think you should be able to understand what I'm asking for.

Comment: That doesn't help, I'm not sure what you're looking for?

Comment: On a high res iPad, the portrait query is not triggering. And in a desktop browser I would like to get rid of the "white gap" at certain resolutions (try resizing the page in Chrome).

Comment: Because of the way my site styles are written I need to keep the "small screen" media query max-width based, and the second one min-width based.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Ian! I think I will have to rethink things a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. I find with media queries things are never exactly 600 or 500 pixels, you often need to change them slightly etc. to get them to work exactly as you want.

Comment: @IanDevlin I think the OP is looking to activate the small screen media query **whenever the device is in portrait mode regardless of the actual viewport width**, so a comma separated media query would be more appropriate.

Comment: That was my next suggestion!